# Is there a way to make a text box or other widget be formatted to be currency? Or format to have two decimals?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking to format my data before it goes into a google sheet.  I would like to format the text entry into packageABox to be currency before/as it goes into google sheets.  Is there a way to format currency or at least format to always have two decimal places when it goes from the text box to it's destination?  Thanks!

```
function doGet(e) {
var app = UiApp.createApplication()
var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
var grid = app.createGrid(70, 1).setId('grid');

var packageALbl = app.createLabel('Bid Pricing: Enter your pricing for Package A *').setId('packageALbl').setVisible(false);
var packageABox = app.createTextBox().setName('packageABox').setId('packageABox').setVisible(false);
grid.setWidget(35, 0, packageALbl);  
grid.setWidget(36, 0, packageABox);
app.getElementById('packageABox').setValue('');

var button = app.createButton('Submit').setId('Submit').setVisible(false);
var submitHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('submit');
submitHandler.addCallbackElement(grid);
button.addClickHandler(submitHandler);

panel.add(grid)
app.add(panel)

return app;
}

function submit(e) {

 //Write the data in the text boxes back to the Spreadsheet
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AhvH2AsQokNfdDFQUVUxM3hqLVhSdnVmUXdrRUlmYXc');
var packageA = e.parameter.packageABox
var range = s.getRange(lastRow+1,2,1,1).setValues([[packageA]]);

  return app;
}
```

Comment: What's the reason to format it before it hits Sheets? Are you going to re-display in the Ui? If we just set the number formatting manually in the Sheets column first, all future values will take on that format.

Answer (score 0):

Format it yourself in submit(). No uiapp element will do it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript functions to achieve that result, there is also a useful [formatString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatString%28String,Object...%29) method in Google Apps Script.(see also [other doc here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf))

an example among others :

```
function test(){
  Logger.log(toCurrency(345678.1));
             }

function toCurrency(val){
  var outString= Utilities.formatString('%2.2f', Number(val));
  return '$'+outString;
}
```

[image]

Note that if you are getting this value in a Handler function using `e.parameter.xxx`, the value will be a string, not a number....

To handle that, simply change like this :

`toCurrency(Number('345678.1'));// convert argument to number`